# Nox Emulator I cannot change my location. How can I fix?

Tags: android-emulator, nox

[It stays this way. The map does not open.]https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee9IP.png

I deleted and reinstalled. I need to change my location. It was working a few days ago. But now I am facing such a problem. I tried a lot of things but couldn't find the solution.